# Robolectric wait for network response

Tags: android, robolectric

I am using Robolectric to test my application that uses retrofit and rxjava. Inside the application every time activity starts, recycler view items are populated dynamically from server. Once recylerview is populated I want to click an item and test that next activity is started. Inside test class Robolectric doesn’t wait for the response so I have to put Thread.sleep. It waits for a fixed time and an item is fetched at line `RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = shadowAdapter.getViewHolder(0);` But I don’t want to put a random thread sleep time in my test case.

We can probably use [CountDownLatch](https://gist.github.com/fmedlin/1773762); I use [OkHttp3IdlingResource](https://github.com/JakeWharton/okhttp-idling-resource) to wait during network calls in Espresso. Is there anything similar in Robolectric?

Is it ok to populate recyclerview with actual network data using roboelectric just like espresso?

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, shadows = {ShadowRecyclerViewAdapter.class})
 public class HomeActivityTest {

    private HomeActivity activity;
    private HomeFragment fragment;

    private ShadowRecyclerViewAdapter shadowAdapter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(HomeActivity.class)
                .create()
                .postCreate(null)
                .start()
                .resume()
                .visible()
                .get();
        assertNotNull(activity);

        fragment = (HomeFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(HomeActivity.TAG_HOME_FRAGMENT);
        assertNotNull(fragment);

        ShadowLog.stream = System.out;

        Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler();

        ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();
    }

    @Test
    public void itemClickShouldStartNewActivity() throws Exception
    {

        RecyclerView recyclerView = ((RecyclerView) fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rv));
        shadowAdapter = customShadowOf(recyclerView.getAdapter());

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        shadowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = shadowAdapter.getViewHolder(0);
        holder.itemView.performClick();
  //        Intent intent = Shadows.shadowOf(activity).peekNextStartedActivity();
  //        assertEquals(NextActivity.class.getCanonicalName(), intent.getComponent().getClassName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robolectric is meant for unit testing. It's a bad practice to use a real network call. You should mock the network stack (e.g. with Mockito)